# What does the "a" instruction do in an SVG path?

Tags: svg

I have read the relevant parts of the SVG specification and do know that "C" stands for cubic segment, "L" stands for line, et.c. but I can not find any documentation on what the "a" instruction does in a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands -- it's an elliptical arc with relative coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#path_A
Has some examples (A rather than a -- simply absolute rather than relative coordinates)
There are some oddities as the starting and ending points of the arc approach one another, as in a circle. It is nice though to have circular segments within a path. One can use C and Q to ensure that the slopes of the arc and that which comes after it are the same at the point of convergence.